# Openid, how do i know whether or not an user has login in

Tags: php, openid

Is there a way that I can check whether or not an user has logged in?

```
if($openid->validate()) {
    // User has logged in
    $_SESSION['identity'] = $openid->identity;
}
```

Does the above code work? Because validate seems not to show anything.

Using the openid.php file provided in the OpenID API

Anyone have any suggestions of how to check whether or not a user has logged in in my website using the correct account? (php)

Comment: it is using the openid class.

Answer (score 1):

I used http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/. There is one file to include and it handles collecting the login info, validating it with the appropriate source and gives you some properties on the openid object to determine if a user has validated and how.